# Save Excel Workbook which is retrieved from API

Tags: excel, vba, api

I have a code which retrieves information from an API. I do get response but here is the tricky part. The response of the API is an Excel file (.xlsx). So when I use the endpoint, I receive an Excel workbook.

My code is as follows (I substituted the links and passwords obviously):

```
    Dim objJsonObject, objRequest As Object
    Dim strUrl, strBody As String
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim blnAsync As Boolean
    
    Me.chbToken.Value = False
    
    With Me.boxTabellen
        .Clear
        .AddItem "Locaties"
        .AddItem "Adressen"
        .AddItem "Zaken"
    End With
        
    Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    strUrl = "https://xxx.xxxxx.xx/xxx/xxxx"
    strBody = "{" & Chr(34) & "username" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "xxxxx" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "password" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "xxxxx" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "group" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "xxxxxx" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "deleteOtherSessions" & Chr(34) & ":true}"
    
    With objRequest
        .Open "Post", strUrl
        .setRequestHeader "authority", "xxxx.xxxxx.xx"
        .setRequestHeader "method", "POST"
        .setRequestHeader "path", "/api/Token"
        .setRequestHeader "scheme", "https"
        .setRequestHeader "accept", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "accept-encoding", "gzip,deflate,br"
        .setRequestHeader "accept-language", "nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
        .setRequestHeader "cache-control", "no-cache"
        .setRequestHeader "content-length", "103"
        .setRequestHeader "authorization", "bearer"
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "dnt", "1"
        .setRequestHeader "expires", "Sat,01Jan200000:00:00GMT"
        .setRequestHeader "origin", "https://xxxx.xxxxx.xx"
        .setRequestHeader "pragma", "no-cache"
        .setRequestHeader "referer", "https://xxxx.xxxxx.xx"
        .setRequestHeader "sec-fetch-dest", "empty"
        .setRequestHeader "sec-fetch-mode", "cors"
        .setRequestHeader "sec-fetch-site", "same-origin"
        .setRequestHeader "sec-gpc", "1"
        .setRequestHeader "user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT10.0;Win64;x64)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,likeGecko)Chrome/104.0.5112.81Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        .send (strBody)
        While objRequest.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        strResponse = .responseText
```

In the end I store the response in a variable (strResponse). If I look at what the response is, we see an Excel workbook:

```
?objRequest.responseText
PK   TU2{FU<  ?   [Content_Types].xml ?(?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ???1?e??8cX8?W???m?³y?g?x0??|?/}}???kH???
?
?E???6?<m#?>7?C?7Bd?????*mHN"????R-?x8?*x?5???V?,V????U?;a????%???I?4?31H?qQJ??????t$+^BZ>?????(?????; t???;i????.<??o? ?9??l~#f???bzM??????d  ?H???}*?2Q.??K     ! ?U0#?L   _rels/.rels ?(?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ??MO???????BKwAH?!T~?I????$?'T?G?~????;#?w????&r?Fq??v???GJy(v??*????K?#F?D??W   ??=??Z?Y??S???7???????9L??bg?|?!?Sh9i?b?r:"y_dl?D???R"4?%??4??   ë?????  ?? PK   TU?  ?   xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels ?(?                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                     ??Kn???b;?<??M7lp??$?e-?????4U????^??C/^?? Y?? ?m?F??W???.?8b????#??Bb????tJ????wL?bwr????????????[N"H?????V?????G??R|??j??i??F?\%?Y1?f???\} PK   TUl?^?  $     xl/workbook.xml??MO???????HhW??pv?????$?N?w???7Q{WS??'??W??W%%1    ????H??þ??j??YeVe?]? ð?? ??,????H(;?z?Y????6:g??_8V??o?? T?5?`y????s>????|?g?d???????C?1?5?~?s??$?,???<??)??XE??V&=?&???h?J?ëv?5????????(??w]?i?n???????????????e?
??/?R??u
[onT??YW
#??q?[??PK   TU&?? ?
```

If I write that string to a .xlsx file:

```
strBestandsnaam = strLocatie & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyyhhmmss") & "_download_" & strTabel & ".xlsx"            
Open strBestandsnaam For Output As #1
Print #1, .responseText
Close #1
```

When I open de .xlsx file, there is an error. It cannot be opened because the file is damaged (according to Excel). Apparently this is not the way to store the information, how can I retrieve the information and save is as an Excel workbook?

EDIT: After consulting @funthomas: I removed all headers I can miss. So the new code is:

```
With objRequest
    .Open "Get", strUrl
    .send
        While objRequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    
    intBestand = FreeFile
    
    Open strBestandsnaam For Binary Access Write As #intBestand

    Put #intBestand, , .responseText

    Close #1
End With
```

But still the same problem

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://vbaoverall.com/download-file-api-web-service-save-desired-format-using-vba/ --> the part using ' CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")' and then writing `responseText` there

Comment: You want `responseBody` not `responseText`  https://bettersolutions.com/vba/web-interaction/http-file-download.htm

Comment: @TimWilliams: I tried as you suggested, but no luck. Just for better understanding: Why do you think that body should do the trick? What is the difference between responseText and responseBody?

Thanks for your reaction!

Comment: @Ike: Interesting link. That is a whole new approach. I will try to follow in a few days.

Also for you: Thanks!

Comment: FYI *request* content-type *is* json, so that header looked fine to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a GET but assuming your file is returned correctly it should work with your POST:

```vb
Sub SaveBinaryResponse()
    
    Const URL = "https://www.blue-bird.com/images/vision2.png"
    
    Dim xmlhttp As Object, strm As Object
    
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", URL, False
    xmlhttp.send
    
    'Use an ADODB stream to save the response to disk
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        .write xmlhttp.responseBody 'not responseText
        .SaveToFile "C:\Temp\test.png", 2
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! That totally did the trick! Now it works just perfect. Just to learn and understand: Why did it not work with my old 'dump-in-a-file-and-open' method and does it work with the ADO stream? What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works in your specific case, but I assume the reason for your problem is caused by the fact that the file is not opened in binary mode and that you use `Print`. Try the following code, I have used it many times writing binary data (eg a Blob from a database) to a file.

```
Dim file as Integer
file = FreeFile
Open strBestandsnaam For Binary Access Write As #file
Put #file, ,.responseText 
Close #file
```

Comment: Hi FunThomas! Thanks for the quick response! I didn't know this way of saving a file. I guess I learned something new today ;) That being said: I am sorry. It doesn't do the trick. It does the same as my code. So it saves the file perfectly but I cannot open it (because it is damaged just like my code). Thanks anyway!

Comment: I assume that you can download and save the file manually (eg via browser) and you can open it with Excel? I would suggest you do so and use a Hex editor to compare that file byte by byte with the file you saved with your code if there is any difference. Let us know the result of your investigations.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I can download and save the file through the browser. I can also do it in Postman by the way (but then you directly save it to .xlsx). Good suggestion to use a Hex editor. I will look into it

Comment: My Hex editing skills are rudimental to say the least ;) but there are so much difference between the two there is no way to start comparing hahaha. The file which I download through the browser is also longer.

Comment: Just saw that the content type to `JSon` - that doesn't sound right.

Comment: No indeed it isn't I tried with deleting all the request headers (all that I can miss in the request) but that doesn't make any difference. I updated the initial question.

Comment: So I would assume that you don't receive an Excel file as result - in that case it's not an Excel/VBA problem but one from you API. I fear I cannot help you with that